# Setting a variable for each for() output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to the world of python and the world of programming in general and i'm coding a programm.
I would like figure out how to create a different global variable for each for() output.
I searched something on Youtube, there and on the official site of Python but nothing.

```
var = (1,2,3,4)
for element in var:
    x_1 = 1
    x_2 = 2
    x_3 = 3
    x_4 = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The short and sweet:

```
x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 = var
```

What is happening is you are matching each variable to each number inside of `var`, this will work if you assign the correct number of variables on the left as there are on the right.

Comment: This does exactly what the question asked for, but I doubt it will actually solve the questioner's actual problem.